# regularity of zero point

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, potential-theory

We consider 1-d process $X$ 
$$ X(t) = b t +  J_{t} + M_{t}$$
where $b$ is constant,  $M$ is a continuous martingale process with 
$M(0) = 0$, and 
$J$ is a symmestric $\alpha$-stable process with its Levy symbol
$\eta(u) = - |u|^{\alpha}$ for some constant  $\alpha\in [1,2)$. Its Levy measure is
$\nu(y) = \frac{1}{|y|^{1+\alpha}}.$ Consider 
$$\tau = \inf\{t>0: X(t) <0\}.$$
I want to know if the following claim is true.

[Claim] $\tau = 0$ almost surely.

[Discussion1]
It is true if $M \equiv 0$.  By Theorem VIII.5 of [Bertoin 1996], 
it yields that
 $$\lim\inf_{t\to 0+} \frac{J_{t}}{(t \ln 1/t)^{1/\alpha}} = - \infty.$$
Therefore, we also have
$$\lim\inf_{t\to 0+} \frac{X(t)}{(t \ln 1/t)^{1/\alpha}} = -\infty,$$
which implies $\tau = 0$.

[Discussion1']
If $M$ is independent to $J$, then the result is trivially extended.

[Discussion2]
It is true if $M = \int_{0}^{t} \sigma_{s} dB_{s}$ for some Brownian motion
with $\sigma_{s} \in [1, 2]$ for all $s\ge 0$. 
In this case, with
$$ \theta(t) = \int_{0}^{t} |\sigma(s)|^{2} ds,$$
there exists $\mathbb P$-Brownian motion $\hat B$ with respect time changed filtration such that
 $$M(t) = \hat B(\theta (t)), \ \mathbb P-a.s.$$
  By Law of Iterated Logarithm , we have
 $$\lim\inf_{t \to 0+} \frac{\hat B(t)}{\sqrt{t}} = -\infty.$$
 Together with the fact 
$1 \le \frac{\theta(t)}{t} \le 4,$
 we obtain
 $$\lim\inf_{t\to 0^{+}} \frac{M(t)}{\sqrt{t}} = -\infty.$$

[Discussion 2'] It is true if $M = \int_{0}^{t} \sigma_{s} dB_{s}$
with $\sigma_{0} \neq 0$ and $\sigma$ is Cadlag process 
by localizing argument.

[Q] My question is if $\tau = 0$ holds for general continuous martingale?
I am particularly interested in the case with
$M_t = \int_{0}^{t} \sigma_{s} dB_{s}$ with $\sigma$ starting from $\sigma(0) = 0$ and possibly correlated to $J$. I need a proof, but also appreciate any clue or related reference you provided.